# C++ Calculation Problem, Always returns $0

Tags: c++, return

I have to display and loop a menu, allowing the customer to make multiple orders for peanuts, movies, or books. The menu displays fine, but the quantity doesn't go down to the calculations part of my code. Everytime I enter a quantity for anything and checkout it returns $0. I have no idea why this is happening I don't see anything wrong with my code, but obviously there is. Do you guys have any suggestions on what to do based on looking at what I have?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//function declarations
void displayMenu();

//constant statements
const double BOOK_PRICE = 9.00;                 //price per book
const double BOOK_SHIPPING = 1.06;              //shipping per book
const double MOVIE_PRICE = 13.99;               //price per movie
const double MOVIE_SHIPPING = .05;              //shipping per movie subtotal
const double PEANUT_PRICE = 1.80;               //price of peanuts per pound
const double SHIPPING_PRICE = .50;              //shipping of peanuts per lb

int main()
{
//declaration statements
    int numBooks = 0;                               //# of books purchased
    int numMovies = 0;                              //# of movies purchased
    double numPeanuts = 0.0;                        //# of peanuts per pound
    double bookSubtotal = 0.0;                      //subtotal of books
    double movieSubtotal = 0.0;                     //subtotal of movies
    double peanutSubtotal = 0.0;                    //subtotal of peanuts
    int totalBooks = 0;                             //running total of books
    int totalMovies = 0;                            //running total of movies
    double totalPeanuts = 0.0;                      //running total of peanuts
    int userChoice = 0;                             //user input    
    double totalPrice = 0.0;                        //final price

    while (userChoice != 4)
    { 
        displayMenu();
        cout << "Enter a menu choice: ";
        cin >> userChoice;

        if (userChoice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the number of books: ";
            cin >> numBooks;
            totalBooks = totalBooks + numBooks;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 2)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the number of movies: ";
            cin >> numMovies;
            totalMovies = totalMovies + numMovies;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the pounds of peanuts as a decimal: ";
            cin >> numPeanuts;
            totalPeanuts = totalPeanuts + numPeanuts;
        }
        else if (userChoice == 4)
        {
            break;          
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input" << endl;
        }

    }

//computations
    bookSubtotal = (totalBooks * BOOK_PRICE) + (totalBooks * BOOK_SHIPPING);
    movieSubtotal = (totalMovies * MOVIE_PRICE * .05) + (totalMovies * MOVIE_PRICE);
    peanutSubtotal = (PEANUT_PRICE * totalPeanuts) + (totalPeanuts * .5);
    totalPrice = bookSubtotal + movieSubtotal + peanutSubtotal;

    cout << "The total price is $" << totalPrice << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}//end of main


void displayMenu()
{
    cout << "1 Books" << endl;
    cout << "2 Movies" << endl;
    cout << "3 Peanuts" << endl;
    cout << "4 Checkout" << endl;
}//end of displayMenu
```

Comment: Add 4 spaces in front of each line of code to have it formatted correctly. Also, if this is homework, please tag it as homework.

Comment: @Josh I tested this on borland, gcc, and msvc and it seems to work fine. What input are you using that's giving the wrong total?

Comment: @Victor I put in a number 1 to select books and then I'll put a number between 1 and 50 and then try to checkout. Still comes out to zero and it's like that with all my other products too.

Comment: Can you run your code in a debugger?  If you put a breakpoint on the cout that shows the total price and then examine the values of the various intermediate values you calculate, what does that tell you (if anything)?

Comment: @Swiss, I was under the impression that the homework was considered a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and as such shouldn't be used. Am I mistaken?

Comment: The code runs in the debugger. I tried the break before the cout of total price and tried to see if totalBooks would display how many books there are at least and it still says 0 when I checkout.

Comment: Add code to print out all of the values at each iteration of the loop. Probably at the end of the loop before the closing curly brace. This will then allow you to have a better idea of what the program is doing and where the error is.

Comment: Also, one last sanity check, are you actually running the executable that you're compiling? I know it has happened to me plenty of times. I'd be changing code, compiling, but actually running an old executable in another directory.

Comment: Nah it's the same exe file. I even try to cout just the total number of books and it still displays your total price is $0. I even took that part of the code out and it still displays that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `cin >>` - you found the answer yourself when you say that the book count is zero. I suggest you try to put `<< endl` after each `cout << ...`. Other solution is to use `_flushall();` after each cout.

Comment: You can also check if the cin was valid by calling cin.good() which returns 0 if the cin reading failed.